# SpaCy machine learning model is capturing longer entities partially. How to resolve it?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have trained a spaCy model on my data using pre-existing en_core_web_sm-2.2.0 model. There are entities in my data which the trained model captures partially.

```
for text in ['KOYA MOTORS PRIVATE LTD.','KOYAL MOTORS PRIVATE LTD.' , 'PUTTAR MOTORS LIMITED' , 'BRENSON MOTORS LIMITED','MITASHI LIMITED','FEDERATION OF KARNATAKA CHAMBERS OF COMMERCE & INDUSTRY' ]:
    print("#####################")
    print(text , nlp_trained(text).ents)
    print("##")
    for i in nlp_trained(text):
        print(i,i.ent_iob_,i.ent_type_,i.pos_,i.tag_,i.head,i.lang_,i.lemma_)
```

Output:

```
#####################
KOYA MOTORS PRIVATE LTD. (MOTORS PRIVATE LTD.,)
##
KOYA O  PROPN NNP LTD en KOYA
MOTORS B ORG PROPN NNP LTD en MOTORS
PRIVATE I ORG PROPN NNP LTD en PRIVATE
LTD I ORG PROPN NNP LTD en LTD
. I ORG PUNCT . LTD en .
#####################
KOYAL MOTORS PRIVATE LTD. (KOYAL MOTORS PRIVATE LTD.,)
##
KOYAL B ORG PROPN NNP LTD en KOYAL
MOTORS I ORG PROPN NNP LTD en MOTORS
PRIVATE I ORG PROPN NNP LTD en PRIVATE
LTD I ORG PROPN NNP LTD en LTD
. I ORG PUNCT . LTD en .
#####################
PUTTAR MOTORS LIMITED (MOTORS LIMITED,)
##
PUTTAR O  NOUN NN LIMITED en puttar
MOTORS B ORG PROPN NNP LIMITED en MOTORS
LIMITED I ORG PROPN NNP LIMITED en LIMITED
#####################
BRENSON MOTORS LIMITED (BRENSON MOTORS LIMITED,)
##
BRENSON B ORG PROPN NNP LIMITED en BRENSON
MOTORS I ORG PROPN NNP LIMITED en MOTORS
LIMITED I ORG PROPN NNP LIMITED en LIMITED
#####################
MITASHI LIMITED ()
##
MITASHI O  PROPN NNP MITASHI en MITASHI
LIMITED O  PROPN NNP MITASHI en LIMITED
#####################
FEDERATION OF KARNATAKA CHAMBERS OF COMMERCE & INDUSTRY (KARNATAKA CHAMBERS OF COMMERCE & INDUSTRY,)
##
FEDERATION O  NOUN NN FEDERATION en federation
OF O  ADP IN FEDERATION en of
KARNATAKA B ORG PROPN NNP CHAMBERS en KARNATAKA
CHAMBERS I ORG NOUN NNS OF en chamber
OF I ORG ADP IN CHAMBERS en of
COMMERCE I ORG PROPN NNP OF en COMMERCE
& I ORG CCONJ CC COMMERCE en &
INDUSTRY I ORG PROPN NNP COMMERCE en INDUSTRY
```

What could be the possible reasons for this issue and how can I rectify it ?

Comment: where do find it's capturing partially? is it in `nlp_trained(text).ents`

Comment: Yes. 
In KOYA MOTORS PRIVATE LTD. (MOTORS PRIVATE LTD.,) , the one in bracket is captured entity. so, 'MOTORS PRIVATE LTD.' is captured instead of 'KOYA MOTORS PRIVATE LTD.' .

Answer (score 0):

The Spacy's `en_core_web_sm-2.2.0` model is not trained for words like `KOYAL`, `KOYA`, etc. One way to make the model predict words like `KOYAL`, `KOYA`, etc is to update the `en_core_web_sm-2.2.0` model.

You can find out more in [here](https://explosion.ai/blog/pseudo-rehearsal-catastrophic-forgetting?ref=Welcome.AI)

The code should look somthing like the following:

```
import random
from spacy.gold import GoldParse
from cytoolz import partition_all
# training data
TRAIN_DATA = [
    ("Where is ICICI bank located", {"entities": [(9, 18, "ORG")]}),
    ("I like Thodupuzha and Pala", {"entities": [(7, 16, "LOC"), (22, 25, "LOC")]}),
    ("Thodupuzha is a tourist place", {"entities": [(0, 9, "LOC")]}),
    ("Pala is famous for mangoes", {"entities": [(0, 3, "LOC")]}),
    ("ICICI bank is one of the largest bank in the world", {"entities": [(0, 9, "ORG")]}),
    ("ICICI bank has a branch in Thodupuzha", {"entities": [(0, 9, "ORG"), (27, 36, "LOC")]}),
]
# preparing the revision data
revision_data = []
for doc in nlp.pipe(list(zip(*TRAIN_DATA))[0]):
    tags = [w.tag_ for w in doc]
    heads = [w.head.i for w in doc]
    deps = [w.dep_ for w in doc]
    entities = [(e.start_char, e.end_char, e.label_) for e in doc.ents]
    revision_data.append((doc, GoldParse(doc, tags=tags, heads=heads,
                                         deps=deps, entities=entities)))
# preparing the fine_tune_data
fine_tune_data = []
for raw_text, entity_offsets in TRAIN_DATA:
    doc = nlp.make_doc(raw_text)
    gold = GoldParse(doc, entities=entity_offsets['entities'])
    fine_tune_data.append((doc, gold))
# training the model
n_epoch = 10
batch_size = 2
for i in range(n_epoch):
    examples = revision_data + fine_tune_data
    losses = {}
    random.shuffle(examples)
    for batch in partition_all(batch_size, examples):
        docs, golds = zip(*batch)
        nlp.update(docs, golds, drop=0.0, losses=losses)
# finding ner with the updated model
nytimes = nlp(sentence)
entities = [(i, i.label_, i.label) for i in nytimes.ents]
print(entities)
```

Comment: I have already trained my model using the method above that's why I mentioned I have trained my model on my data. I want to understand what steps should I take to further improve my model. I am hoping if somebody can point what this type of model output signifies for the model and the training action that I should take.

Comment: how big was your TRAIN_DATA?